# set ng-init on select with scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I have a directive that I am trying to set the `ng-init` to a variable set with `$scope`

```
<select ng-init="safe.id=currentSafe" ng-options="safe as safe.name for safe in safes track by safe.id" ng-model="safe" ng-change="getSafeUrl(safe.id)"></select>
```

In the `link` function on the directive I have:

```
$scope.currentSafe = '72824ca7-99ab-4f16-a56c-3c98328c73fd';
```

This is not working.  However if I change the template to read:

```
<select ng-init="safe.id='72824ca7-99ab-4f16-a56c-3c98328c73fd'" ng-options="safe as safe.name for safe in safes track by safe.id" ng-model="safe" ng-change="getSafeUrl(safe.id)"></select>
```

Why am I not able to use a string from `$scope` but I can use it directly?

Comment: Is this not working either? `safe.id={{currentSafe}}`

Comment: Use your controller to initialize scope variables. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit. Is safe defined anywhere? There is not enough info.

Comment: @klauskpm that does not work, it throws an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You should not use [select as with track by](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/select#-select-as-and-track-by-), they are not designed to work together. See documentation for details.

2) Do not use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for initializing property which should be done on the controller, ng-inited expressions are not watched, set `$scope.safe.id` on the link/controller function of the directive itself. In your case you might be setting `currentSafe` asynchronously but ng-init would have evaluated it already by then.

```
<select ng-options="safe.name for safe in safes track by safe.id" 
        ng-model="safe" 
        ng-change="getSafeUrl(safe.id)"></select>
```

and set:

```
$scope.safe = {id:whateverid}
```

Comment: if I can't use `track by` how do I get the ID's into the values of the `<option>` tags?

Comment: As i said you cannot use both, dint say you should not use track by :). Please read my answer and the linked documentaion section.